# Fill array objects with the same data or use a pointer?

Tags: c++, object, pointers

I'm developing a game using c++ and I don't know what's the better approach to my problem.
I have an array with `gameObject` objects, each one has an array with frames of animation that I loop through to show the animation in the game.
The animations are time based and I have to tell the objects how much time has passed since the last frame was displayed (`deltaTime`) to calculate what frame I will display in this iteration.
Everything ok until here.
Is it ok to feed the `deltaTime` to the objects with a setter method? Or would be better if I had a pointer in each object to a global variable? Or is there another even better approach here regarding performance and organization? Keep in mind that there'll be hundreds of objects.
Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Do the objects have an update function? If that's the case, pass it to that function. Avoid unnecessary state.

Comment: No, but that's a good idea. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, avoid global variables. Just loop over the objects, passing the `deltaTime` to each:

```
for (auto &gameObject : gameObjects)
{
    gameObject.Update(deltaTime);
}
```

Storing the time within each object isn't recommended, since anything you think you might need it for "in the future", you should just do within `Update`.

Comment: An update function should work great. Only using the value and not storing it anywhere. Thank you.